# highcharts piechart - pie size customize

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I want piechart style -->
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXDkL.png)

but my code make this style -->[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX9YR.png)

how to can i make pie size 45% > 30% > 10% > 5%

Comment: I don't think this is supported by standard Highcharts charts, but you can use many series and inside this series you can change their innerSize and size. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/p7hfpwc2/1/

Comment: thank you Grzegorz Blachliński. that's good idea :b